# How reset database back to initial state in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, schema, auto-generate

I am currently working on a ROR project. I had generated the scaffold for Notes and run the migrations for it. However now we had a little change of plans and I want to get the app back to the initial state. So I run rails scaffold destroy notes and so I had all files generated erased. But I still have the file schema.rb  with the Notes table migration defined. How do I get rid of it without changing manually this file (which is considered bad practice)? If I generate the Notes model and run the migration is this file going to update and everything will be fine? Or there could be conflicts? 
I tried to run rake db:reset. It seems to have not worked. But still in the end of the process I got this message.

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"thenotesapp", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"thenotesapp", "password"=>"thenotesapp"}
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")    -> 0.0367s
-- create_table("notes", {:force=>:cascade})    -> 0.0628s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()    -> 0.0276s
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")    -> 0.0251s
-- create_table("notes", {:force=>:cascade})    -> 0.0157s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()    -> 0.0012s
```

schema.rb remains like this scaffold destroyed

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150114071920) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "notes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "text"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: Try `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` to get a fresh `schema.rb`.

Comment: Editing migrations is bad practice for a reason: already deployed applications should be able to update their schema on upgrade. If the app is not yet deployed anywhere and you're researching, there's no harm in changing migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To drop the database you have to firstly set it, as you've said to *initial state* - to do so run:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
```

Next step would be to remove all migration files (`/db/migrate` directory) manually.

That's it - you have clean `schema.rb` containing no tables.

Comment: sorry..new here ..thought upvote meant accept answer. My bad. Would appreciate upvote on my question if you find it valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First drop the database:

```
rake db:drop
```

Then create db:

```
rake db:create
```

After that migrate tables:

```
rake db:migrate
```

If you want to populate database, then:

```
rake db:seed
```

Answer (score 0):

`rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed`